# MODX Revo tvFilter with getResources and/or pdoResources

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I have a checkbox-TV:
City 1||City 2||City 3||City 4

With getResources and pdpResources tvFilter wont't work. Only if I check
only on of the "Citys". If I check 2 or more nothing worked.

```
&tvFilters=`art.start-city==yes%,art.city==%City 2%`
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try and combine the parameters with an & character or the word AND?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your problem is in &tvFilters value. I had similar problem and solved it by adding % to the value.
Try this:

```
&tvFilters=`art.start-city==%yes%,art.city==%City 2%`
```